# Wordpress autoupdate

Tags: wordpress, plugins, auto-update

Info:

- Wordpress ver. 4.7
- OSver. Ubuntu 14

I want to enable auto-update wordpress core, plugins and themes. In file `wp-config.php` I added:

```
define( 'AUTOMATIC_UPDATER_DISABLED', false );
define( 'WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', true );
```

Also in file `/wp-includes/functions.php`

```
add_filter( 'auto_update_plugin', '__return_true' );
add_filter( 'auto_update_theme', '__return_true' );
```

And this settings do not upgrade core, plugins and themes to newest version.

Also I use plugins e.g:

- Easy Updates Manager
- Companion Auto Update
- Simple Automatic Updates

This plugins do not work.

Answer (score 2):

you must set this code in your wp-config:

```
define( 'WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', true );
//this is by default false
```

and add this to your functions.php

```
// Disable dev core update
add_filter( 'allow_dev_auto_core_updates', '__return_false' );
// Enable Plugin auto update
add_filter( 'auto_update_plugin', '__return_true' );
add_filter( 'auto_update_theme', '__return_true' );
```

The first line enables all core updates,
and the second line disable the dev core update.

**Make shure that the file permissions match on your server!**

if this is not working look at your error-log and give us the output

Comment: If I add somenthing on ./wp-includes/functions.php I have that my service is unavailable

Comment: you must add this to /wp-content/themes/youtheme/functions.php

Comment: So in all plungins I have to add this part of code ?

Comment: I add to ./wp-content/themes/my_theme/functions.php and still it is not update my plugins, theme and core